# REST API including and excluding of subresources

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am trying to determine a RESTful way to have subresources included and excluded at will for specific requests.

For example sake, this could be the original request:

**GET departments/321**

```
200 (Ok)
{
    "id": "321",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
    "subdepartments": [
       {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "Training"
       },
       {
          "id": "224",
          "name": "Book Sales"
       }
       ...
    ]
}
```

There could be a big list of sub departments.  The `GET departments` resource would also then include every department AND each of those departments' subdepartments. A lot of data.

This could be solved by creating two separate resources:

**GET departments/321**

```
200 (Ok)
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
}
```

**GET departments/321/subdepartments**

```
200 (Ok)
[
   {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Training"
   },
   {
      "id": "224",
      "name": "Book Sales"
   }
   ...
]
```

But there may be occasions where the client software would prefer not to make multiple requests (for performance sake most likely). Perhaps by providing an `include` filter:

**GET departments/321?include=subdepartments**

```
200 (Ok)
{
    "id": "321",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
    "subdepartments": [
       {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "Training"
       },
       {
          "id": "224",
          "name": "Book Sales"
       }
       ...
    ]
}
```

Or an exclude filter:

**GET departments/321?exclude=subdepartments**

```
200 (Ok)
{
    "id": "321",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
}
```

Although perhaps we need to include a link to the subresource if its excluded?

**GET departments/321?exclude=subdepartments**

```
200 (Ok)
{
    "id": "321",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
    "subdepartments": {
        "href" : "api.com/departments/321/subresources"
    }
}
```

**Is there an acceptable RESTful way of performing the above including or excluding of subresources?**

Comment: What you propose looks good to me. I think RESTful shouldn't be used too strict. If your world doesn't fit into REST than REST should be bended - not the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper REST services must use hypermedia (links) to connect to related resources. If we use a custom media type instead of something like JSON Collection or AtomPub, the response for the first call would look something like

```
{
    "id": "321",
    "name": "Sales",
    "building": "The Foundary"
    "links": [
          { "rel": "subdepartments", "href": "departments/321/subdepartments", "method": "get" }
     ]
}
```

You can call that link to get a resource with links to all subdepartments.

```
{
    ...
    "links": [
      { "rel": "subdepartment", "href": "departments/321/subdepartments/1", "method": "get" },
      { "rel": "subdepartment", "href": "departments/321/subdepartments/2", "method": "get" }
    ]
}
```

It works almost like browsing a web-site and clicking the links.

Read this blog post by Roy Fielding himself:
http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

There are obvious complexity and performance issues that could happen in this approach. Truely RESTful services make sense when the server app can evolve separately from the client. Otherwise, just use the approach with query string parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any value in providing the href like in my last example?

Comment: It really depends on the client consuming the service. It might be a good idea to provide links by default and have some OData style `$expand=true` query parameter to replace links with actual resources.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything in REST is a *must*.

Comment: @Opal Roy Fielding, the person first described the REST architecture in his dissertation, said that in his blog. There is nothing wrong with basic HTTP based services that use URLs as endpoints, but they are not truely RESTful.

Comment: @DmitryS. That was gonna be my question: when should I return  resource links vs resource representations for a collection URI? What is the 'RESTful' way of doing it and is it valid to sometimes break the rules?
For example, you say that GET "departments/321/subdepartments" should return a list of links to all sub-departments. If I need to show all sub-departments details in a table, and there are 5000 then I would need 5000 GET requests to each URI... is that efficient? I think in that case a single GET that includes all resources would be more efficient. Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Answer (score 2):

I dont have any problem to add those parameters, so go ahead and use it, the most important part is that you manage the http status code, an the response have a good structure to read the data (and you have it!)

Also, if you want see another way, tru with OData: [Web API and OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like a very good fit for http://jsonapi.org/ – It's "your anti-bikeshedding weapon" when it comes about structuring your JSON responses. Reading through the spec might take some time at first, compared to implementing your own ad-hoc schema, but it really pays off.
The spec also consists a part a [section about "compound documents"](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) that also makes use of a `include=…` parameter to fetch multiple documents/resources with one request.